# Copy/pasting from QGIS to Excel

Tags: qgis, excel

I want to copy and paste (or export) data from a query (or attribute table) into excel.

I've tried copying and pasting direct from a query results (in DB Manager) or loaded the query result as a layer, and done the same from the attribute table.

But in excel, if there is a linefeed or carriage return character (or both) in any cell of the query results, this gets split across multiple rows in excel.

Is there a way to control or avoid this behaviour?

Comment: In the attribute table right click Select All (or a selection) and 'Copy Cell Content' works. Paste into Notepad and remove the returns before excel.

Comment: I get the same, I suggest the behaviour of copy and paste from the attribute table has changed from a few years ago (where CRs did not interfere). At the moment I workaround by right clicking on the layer and using Exporting Features as XLXS .     I note, I don't get that with query tables in DBMan, these copy and paste OK in my experience.

Comment: Right click on the layer with the selection -> export -> Save selected feature as.. -> and choose the format Ms Office Excel

Comment: Do you have pandas python module installed? (`import pandas`)

Comment: What is pandas python? I can't find it in plug ins. What does it do?

Comment: Saveas excel from Christophe and BJW works - thanks.